# XAMPP: cannot find /var/www/html

Tags: apache2, xampp, html, www

I downloaded the latest [XAMPP deb file](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) and installed it.

But apparently, there is no `/var/www` folder.

Can anyone tell me the default location of the Apache's *DocumentRoot* directory within XAMPP installation?

Comment: I don't use it so I am guessing it's in `/opt/lampp` either called `www` or `htdocs` depending I guess on ure Ubuntu version...which is ure version?

Comment: @ElderGeek, yes meant that was a typo!

Comment: check here `/opt/lampp/htdocs` or `/opt/lampp/www`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `DocumentRoot` directory within the XAMPP installation is `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`. But if you have installed so called *Apps* or *Add-ons* (WordPress, MediaWiki, etc.) their `DocumentRoot` directories will be placed into `/opt/lampp/apps/<app>/htdocs` (`/opt/lampp/apps/wordpress/htdocs`, `/opt/lampp/apps/mediawiki/htdocs`, etc.).

---

The necessary information could be found in the article *Configure Virtual Hosts* from section *HOW-TO Guides* from the default page of XAMPP, which can be found at `http://localhost`.

[image]

In my opinion - under Linux - XAMPP makes the things unnecessarily complicated.

---

**Update:** Here is a simple relevant article:

- [How to setup a Virtual Host locally with XAMPP in Ubuntu](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/302/how-to-setup-a-virtual-host-locally-with-xampp-in-ubuntu)