# How do I setup DVWA on Ubuntu?

Tags: server, apache2, localhost

I am setting up a DVWA environment and I want the directory and its files to be displayed on my browser. I have copied the DVWA files in the www folder and deleted all the files that were previously on the folder.

Now when I go to local host via my browser I get the error The requested URL / was not found on this server. I have confirmed my apache is well up and running.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I wanted to view the directory from firefox by typing localhost but instead i get an error message saying The requested URL / was not found on this server

Comment: I decided to look at this app and created short manual how to install it within Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Hi, Ian, if you use XAMPP instead of the native LAMP stack, please, check the bottom of my updated [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/956378/566421).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step guide how to setup [DVWA](https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/blob/master/README.md) within Ubuntu 16.04 and the default Apache's configuration:

**Pre-Requirements**

The standard Ubuntu LAMP stack, that means we have working Apache2, MySQL, PHP. Refs:

- [What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)
- [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki: Apache MySQL PHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
- [Linode: How to Install a LAMP Stack on Ubuntu 16.04.](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

Along with next additional PHP extensions:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-curl php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml php-xmlrpc
```

**1. Download DVWA via Git**

First install Git if it is not installed - `sudo apt install git` - and then:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo git clone https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA.git
```

- The above command will download the application into the folder `/var/www/html/DVWA`.

**2. Create configuration file**

Create the configuration file `/var/www/html/DVWA/config/config.inc.php`:

```
sudo cp /var/www/html/DVWA/config/config.inc.php.dist /var/www/html/DVWA/config/config.inc.php
```

Edit the configuration file in this way (lines from 18 to 21):

```
$_DVWA = array();
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = 'localhost';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwaDatabase';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'dvwaUser';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'dvw@~User~p@$$w0rd';
```

- Where `dvwaDatabase`, `dvwaUser` and `dvw@~User~p@$$w0rd` are subject of your decision.
- To edit the file via Nano type: `sudo nano /var/www/html/DVWA/config/config.inc.php`.
- To save the changes and close Nano use <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**3. Grant writable permissions**

You should change the ownership of certain files and folders to Apache's user `www-data`:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/DVWA/hackable/uploads/
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/DVWA/external/phpids/0.6/lib/IDS/tmp/phpids_log.txt
```

**4. Create MySQL Database**

The steps are:

- Login to the MySQL server from a terminal.
- Create Database.
- Create User.
- Grant all privileges on the Database to the user.
- Reload the privileges from the grant tables in the MySQL database.
- Exit MySQL.

The commands are:

```
$ mysql -u'root' -p                                                  
Enter password: *enter mysql root's password*

mysql> CREATE DATABASE dvwaDatabase;
mysql> CREATE USER 'dvwaUser'@'localhost' identified by 'dvw@~User~p@$$w0rd';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dvwaDatabase.* TO 'dvwaUser'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit
```

- Don't miss the semicolon (`;`) at the end of each sentence.

**5. Enable certain PHP functions**

Edit the existing `/var/www/html/DVWA/config/.htaccess` file with this content:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag allow_url_fopen On
php_flag allow_url_include On
php_flag display_errors On
```

I'm [not sure](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/issues/685) you are really need to enable the function `allow_url_include`, but to do this you should edit your `php.ini` file, because this option is [disabled by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5593273/6543935). The default PHP version, within Ubuntu 16.04, is PHP7.0, so your `php.ini` file is located in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/` edit the file with Nano text editor and use <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to find `allow_url_include`, then change the line in this way:

```
allow_url_include = On
```

You can do the above step with a single command using `sed`:

```
sudo sed 's/allow_url_include = Off/allow_url_include = On/' /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini -i.bak
```

Check if the value is changed and restart Apache:

```
cat /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini | grep allow_url_include
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

**6. Open DVWA and continue with its setup**

Open your browser and type: **`http://localhost/DVWA/`**. Initially you should use `user: admin` and `passwd: admin`, but next you should use `user: admin` and `passwd: password`.

[image]
That's it.

---

**Further reading**

- How to update: [`man git-pull`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/git-pull.1.html) or [Git pull contents without affecting the local file changes...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426567/git-pull-contents-without-affecting-the-local-file-changes-and-vice-versa)
- Advanced VirtualHost configuration: [1] [How to setup an additional VirtualHost](https://askubuntu.com/a/949315/566421), [2] [How to use a domain name for my local needs](https://askubuntu.com/a/941305/566421), [3] [Another example - WP install](https://askubuntu.com/a/941947/566421), [4] [How to set a domain to ip address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900523/how-to-set-a-domain-to-ip-address), [5] [How to create and enable Let's Encrypt HTTPS certificate](https://askubuntu.com/a/900433/566421).
- If you using **XAMPP** instead of the native LAMP stack the default `DocumentRoot` directory should be [**`/opt/lampp/htdocs`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/888638/566421) instead of `/var/www/html` and I think it is the only difference according the above guide.