# http://localhost/example/ test.php not working?

Tags: apache2, php, xampp

when i run command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.1.11-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

My file location is /var/www/example/test.php

Comment: I think the default page should be accessible via `http://localhost`

Comment: Don't understand your  comment

Comment: It means type `http://localhost` into the browser and you should see the default home page!

Comment: when i type http://localhost then shows http://localhost/dashboard/ page

Comment: It looks XAMPP is working. It's mot clear - what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want  localhost//xampp/ url work properly

Comment: Hi, @NadimTareq. Doesn't my answer met your question?

Comment: Yes your answer is good

Comment: Hello pa4080 How I   /var/www/html/example/test.php file show my browser? but try http://localhost/example/test.php but not work

Comment: Hi, @NadimTareq, I couldn't understood your last question, please paraphrase it. Use `at sign` in front of my nick name to ping me: `@pa4080`.

Comment: I question only you ..i  do not  know your actual name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, to access `http://localhost/xampp` within the default configuration of XAMPP you must:

- Create a sub dir called `xampp/` into the `DocumentRoot` directory. The default `DocumentRoot` of XAMPP is `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` - [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/888638/566421):

  ```
  sudo mkdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp
  ```
- Create a simple `index.html` or `index.php` file:

  ```
  echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | sudo tee /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/index.php
  ```

  The above command will create `index.php` file in the directory `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/`, that will contain the code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

If that works and you are able to see a page as [this shown here](https://wiki.gandi.net/_media/en/hosting/using-linux/tutorials/phpinfo.jpg), you must read the documentation of XAMPP and some relevant articles to gain a basic knowledge: [How to setup a Virtual Host locally with XAMPP in Ubuntu](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/302/how-to-setup-a-virtual-host-locally-with-xampp-in-ubuntu).